# How do I prevent a regex from matching every other match in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that matches any number after a pound sign.

```
(^|\W)#(\d+)(\W|$)
```

I have the following text

```
#123321
#123321
#123321
#123321
```

Pasting this into http://regexpal.com/ note how the regex only matches every other #number. How do I make it so the regex matches each instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use multiline flag:

```
/(^|\W)#(\d+)($|\W)/mg
                    ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK6aU8/2)

The multiline flag forces `^` to match at the beginning of a line, and `$` to match at the end of the line. It is also advised to place `$` as the first element of the alternation, although in this case, it is not a big problem since you are only matching one `\W`.

To enable the search of multiple values on one line, use a version of the regex with a loof-ahead:

```
/(^|\W)#(\d+)(?=$|\W)/mg
             ^------^
```

Or even shorter:

```
/(^|\W)#(\d+)(?!\w)/mg
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK6aU8/5)

The lookahead will not conumer characters, it will just check for the end-of-line or a non-word character presence after the digits, and then it will be able to check the same character during the next iteration.

Comment: It is also skipping #4545 #445445 #445454 when they are on the same line. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Yes, because you use a capturing group. Use a look-ahead: `(^|\W)#(\d+)(?=$|\W)`. I see what you need, you are trying to emulate `(?<!\w)#\d+(?!\w)`. You may use it as `(^|\W)#\d+(?!\w)` actually.

Answer (score 0):

Add the global and multiline flags  `/(^|\W)#(\d+)(\W|$)/gm` at the end of your expression. Worked for me at regexr.com